# Use of the possessive apostrophe in a list

Tags: saxon-genitive, compound-possessives

If I was to label something

> The Poets and Painters' Distillery

do I only apply the possessive apostrophe after 'Painters' as in the text written above, or do I also need to apply one to 'Poets' so that it becomes

> The Poets' and Painters' Distillery ?

I'm thinking the former is correct, but cannot be too sure.

Answer (score 20):

You are right. If the distillery is jointly possessed by the poets and painters then you only need the apostrophe after Painters.

Similarly, *John and Mary's house* is the house owned jointly by John and Mary. If John and Mary each have their own houses, then you need apostrophes after both possessive nouns: *John's and Mary's houses*. Note, however, that to remove any ambiguity as to how many houses each has you need to repeat the possessed noun: *John's house and Mary's houses*.

Comment: +1 confirm I was about to write the same when I saw Shoe's answer.

Comment: +1 But John may have two houses and Mary three. Then "John's and Mary's houses" is unambiguous (although some information is not provided).

Comment: bib, agreed. To remove all ambiguity you would need to specify as follows: _John's one house and Mary's two houses / John's two houses and Mary's three houses ... e.g. have been repossessed._

Comment: @Shoe, “John’s one house” is not really necessary: if ‘house’ is kept in the singular, you know there is only one. “John’s house and Mary’s three houses” works equally well (or awkwardly).