# "Sally & Rhod's Wedding" - where should the apostrophe go?

Tags: apostrophe

"Sally & Rhod's Wedding" - where should the apostrophe go?

Comment: Where you've put it.

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120449/use-of-the-possessive-apostrophe-in-a-list/120452#120452

Comment: What Barrie said, but more to the point, *where else* are you considering putting it? I can't think of other places, so it's quite unclear to me what the question actually is. And the answer you accepted makes this general reference, because that holds for any and all nouns.

Comment: I am aware that the apostrophe comes after plurals e.g. "birds' (belonging to all the birds)". Well I wasn't sure if the apostrophe came after the "s". What are the grammatical components of the sentence in the original question?

Comment: ...the subject is the wedding and the possessive pronoun is "Sally and Rhod"?

Comment: The apostrophe goes after an s _that is already there_ for a plural. It doesn't if there isn't already an s there (e.g. _the children's room_). If a singular word ends with an s, there is some disagreement about when to add _'s_ and when to add just an apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it correct.  You would not want to place the apostrophe after the s in Rhod.  That would imply that it belonged to multiple Rhods.  (i.e. Rhods')

Comment: Further, the owner of the wedding is "Sally & Rhod" as a collective, so you'd not want to say "Sally's & Rhod's".  You do indeed have it correct.

Comment: Yes. If they had two separate weddings, you could say "Sally's and Rhod's weddings", however.