# Do any style guides recommend an apostrophe at the end for double possessors? (John and Jacks' house)

Tags: possessives, writing-style, apostrophe, style-manuals

I am aware that the universally accepted style is to put an apostrophe-*s* at the end of the second possessor's name.

**Example**: *Amy and Steve's car*

My question is *not* whether that is the common rule; I know it is.

My question is whether anyone knows of a style guide, grammar, or other authority that condones writing this in the usual style of a plural possessor; that is, with an apostrophe on the *end* of the compound/plural owner's name:

```
John and Jacks' house

John Merrill, Stephen Arthur, Chuck Williams, and Donald Smiths' law firm
```

Thanks!

Comment: Apostrophes can only do so much; they're silent, after all. How would you **say** the two different sentences with different meanings? If there are two different meanings -- and if there aren't, what's the problem?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120449/use-of-the-possessive-apostrophe-in-a-list

Comment: @JohnLawler It's a question about written style.

Comment: Yeah, but that just means it's a question about representing spoken language in print. _Written style_ has to do with details of the representation, as long as they don't obscure the representation. If you would ***say*** _Amy's and Steve's car_, as opposed to _Amy and Steve's car_, by all means write it. I can think of several reasons why I might prefer two possessives instead of one -- for instance, to leave the way open for an inference that, while Amy and Steve are joint owners of the car, they are not a couple, which is at least an invited inference of _Amy and Steve's car_

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm sorry but I don't follow your point. You think I shouldn't be asking about correct written style because the expressions sound the same?

Comment: I'm saying "correct written style" is not worth paying any attention to. It's nothing but opinion anyway; simply looking at how apostrophes are used tells one that much. Punctuating a sentence strangely will not make up for constructing it in a confusing way in the first place. Start over and make it clear first; **then**, if you can't help youself, worry about punctuation.

Comment: I think many hundreds of years is just enough time for it to have become common knowledge that the Saxon genitive is built using 's and never s'. It is perfectly clear that there are no style guides that recommend the latter, because the latter does not so much as exist. However, it is also perfectly clear that you are welcome to write any number of style guides yourself, and have them say anything you please. And it perfectly clear you can't expect anyone to follow them, especially if they recommend things that do not so much as exist.

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ I have no idea why you closed my question; it is perfectly clear what I'm asking, even if you don't like it. Regarding your comment, that "the Saxon genitive is built using 's and never s'," you seem to have completely overlooked the genitive plural, which is what I'm talking about.

Comment: First of all, I've always seen firms called by the partners's last names, never first and last names. Secondly, there's no need for the apostrophe. It's should be: *Meril, Arthur, Williams & Smith Law Firm* And lastly, if I'm not mistaken, when the possessive apostrophe  is used then only the senior partner's name is mentioned. In your example, it would be Merril, because the senior and most important partner is usually mentioned first. Hence it would Merril's offices are located in NYC, or (very unlikely) Merril's Law Firm but I doubt any partner would agree to that latter formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do an exhaustive search of usage manuals -- and I don't think it's worth your while to either, because

> John and Jacks' house

would mean the house belong to John and Jacks, where *Jacks* is the name of one person.  (Perhaps it's a nickname.)

So... nice idea, but I don't think it will fly.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't answer my question.

Comment: Also, I disagree with your claim that a house belonging to a "John" and a "Jacks" would be "John and Jacks' house." I think it would instead be "John and Jacks's house" (as it would be "John and Chris's house").

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this question. I sometimes wonder and would sometimes want reliable references for some language styles. I saw an article [Possessive with Two Nouns](https://writingtips.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/possessive-with-two-nouns/)  which says--

"The possessive case can be confusing, especially when two nouns are doing the possessing. Fortunately, **The Chicago Manual of Style** sheds light on this conundrum. [emphasis mine]

"Chicago says that when two nouns “possess” the same entity, only the second takes an apostrophe (‘):

my aunt and uncle’s house

Gilbert and Sullivan’s lolanthe

Minneapolis and Saint Paul’s transportation system"

https://writingtips.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/possessive-with-two-nouns/

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a style guide. Most gramnars mention this special kind of s-genitive:

- I've just been to Peter and Zoe's flat.

This is much more usual than "Peter's and Zoe's flat. Source: Oxford Guide to English Grammar, John Eastwood, section 146e.

Comment: ... unless both Peter and Zoe have their own flat, in which case it's *Peter's and Zoe's flats*.

Comment: @Peter Shor  I think that in case of too different flats the formulation should make this clear.

Comment: Thank you, but I regret this doesn't answer my question. (Answers a different question, though.)

Answer (score -1):

John and Jacks' house mean, the house belongs to John and more than one Jack.

Where Paul's chair, the chair belongs to Paul. If there were two or more Paul's and they each own a chair, you would write; Pauls' chairs.

If John and Jack each own a chair, would you write, John's and Jack's chair. They each own a chair. John's and Jack's chairs, they both own multiple chairs.

Where they jointly own a chair. John's and Jack's chair, or John and Jack's chair. The latter sounds correct, but the apostrophe clearly indicate they jointly own a single chair. Both are correct.

You may also consider ordering the names alphabetically I.e. Jack's and John's chair.

Where we have many Jack's and many John's each owning many chairs, then it's Jacks' and Johns' chairs.  "Please can the Jacks' and the Johns' put your chairs away".

Source: Eats, Shoots & Leaves: The Zero Tolerance Approach to Punctuation

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Unfortunately this does not answer the question at the top of the page, which appears to explain the downvote. Your post appears to be asking more questions. Please do take the [tour] — Stack Exchange is not a discussion site and does not encourage discussions.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.